# Marker Cluster mapbox android

Tags: mapbox, markerclusterer

I have a problem with Markers in MapBox.
I have multi markers and i want to clustering it.
I using MapBox SDK for android.
Please help me. Thanks so much.

I had using markerscluster with Google Service Map Android v2. with Lib "Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility"
But i can't using like it for MapBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [mapbox Android plugin repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android), there is a [clustering plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/pull/49) now, but it doesn't seem to be in maven yet.

(The gl core implementation of mapbox also has a clustering [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5814).)

Comment: Thanks for help me! But now i'm using diffirent algorithm for clusting markers from server. It's very quick and perfomance high. If u like it. I'll show for u!

Comment: FYI, here's the dependency you need to add: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/162#issuecomment-343239564

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw this demo?
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk
There is example with cluster in project. According to that project you just have to use method setClusteringEnabled in MapView, where last parameter is minimum zoom level to do clustering

Comment: Thanks for supporter. That's a old question. And I had a Filter Markers for that problem.
And ClusteringEnabled of Mapbox is new Update from SDK.

Comment: That link is dead, and there is no such method on MapView.

Answer (score 0):

The Clustering Plugin @Diederik mentioned is now [deprecated](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/522).

The supported way to do this now is Data Clustering, here's the example https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/clustering/#symbollayer